# SDL libsdl1.2-dev

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I have a problem when i try to load the SDL libsdl1.2-dev, library. It is recognized by my ide (Clion) but when tryng to compile this:

compile results are:

```
    main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
```

same for quit of course,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); 
    SDL_Quit(); 
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I am working with Windows ubuntu subsystem and I give myself less than 2 hours to create a tetris.

Comment: It is my very first question here... I receive a -1.... Why. The guy who put this -1 could help me no?

Answer (score 0):

Like this ok

```
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra main.c `sdl-config --cflags`
gcc -o executable main.o `sdl-config --libs`
```

But no display even with xming on WLS

Comment: I guess there is a X window issue with wls?

Answer (score 0):

I think the include is just `#include <SDL.h>` and not `<SDL/SDL.h>`

UPDATE - translation for installation instructions (PS. my french sucks)
1. download SDL - https://www.libsdl.org/
2. source code - not required (unless curious)
   runtime libraries - 
Option 1: SDL.dll important library, recommended to be in the same directory as the project. If you opt for this option, you need to manually link the DLL in your project. Distribute the dll with project.
Option 2: SDL.dll copied in Windows library. If opted, then no need to manually link when executing the project.
3. Development libraries - these files are only necessary for the programmer, no need to distribute them with the project.
4. Three versions exist on windows:
a) VC6 - for Visual Studio 6 (old version, rarely used)
b) VC8 - for visual studio 2005 (libraries found on site)
c) mingw32 - for CodeBlocks users

Now you need to download the Development Libraries and just create a new project in your preferred editor and link the project to the DLL if it is not included in windows system directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don t think so, if it was the cae it would not compile. I am gonna try on windows directly instead of WSL

Comment: bucket list : get blessed by random programmer on stack overflow ---- check

Answer (score 0):

for Windows here is (in French) the answer

https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/19980-apprenez-a-programmer-en-c/17117-installation-de-la-sdl

Good luck folks

This really sucks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand it is so complicated!!!
Once, i will have fully understand, i will code something to simplify all this
Has someone already worked with this?
maybe, i ve missed something with make
Such a long time without C
But Maven and gradle import dependencies in Java